# Jquery can't load updated JSON file

Tags: jquery, json

I have a local server (vagrant) and I'm loading a JSON file through jquery.
Every time I want to change the json file I need to create a new file because the jquery (getJSON) gets error if the file isnt identical as the first time imported.

I guess it's something in the ubuntu local server, but I can't figure out what.

Someone have any idea?

Comment: getJSON does not compare the past and the new status of the file. May be after changes you receive file with incorrect JSON format, or a problem with the rights on the file.

Comment: What kind of error it gives?

Comment: Any simple change like "name":"aa" changed for "name":"aab" will cause the problem. If I restart the computer it will work with the new change.

Comment: Request: parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
FOR:
var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
console.log( "Request: " + err );